# CSS animation moving and changing color

Tags: css, css-animations

I am not that familiar with CSS animations. My client want to achieve [the following result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/byxuef26nj6o7te/CSS%20Hover%20Effect.jpg?dl=0) when hovering the `contact` button:

so to be clear:

1. the square's move from left to right and vice versa
2. when the square moves, the line underneath it changes color

the top image it the start state, the middle is during the effect (50%) and the bottom image is the end stage.

Is this achievable with only CSS or do I need JS as well?
How would I approach this?

Comment: It is achievable via css only. can you share your code so far? did you try it yourself? are you stuck with something? People here will be happy to assist you, but not to write code for you from scratch :-)

Comment: use css. js not required

Comment: @RonenCypis thanks for your helpful answer. I recieved the request from a client and am wondering how much I need to charge for it. Therefore I am looking for an indication on how to approach this. I did not yet try something since I did not start with the project. Do you have any idea how much time it would cost to do this for somebody who has basic knowledge of animations but good knowledge of CSS overall?

Comment: @BorisKamp if you know how, it shouldn't take more than a few minutes. If you don't- it depends on how fast you can search and learn new stuff...

Comment: Check my answer below, hope it will get you started easily...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a quick and dirty JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/x0b397pb/

As you can see, it is possible with just CSS. In this example I used pseudo elements (`::before` and `::after`) to create most of the elements.

You mentioned "Im not that familiar with CSS animations". [For this I used transitions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```
transition: left 1000ms, right 1000ms, box-shadow 1000ms;
```

Each comma separated element is a value that will transition between 2 points. This transition happens on a change of the div, this can be on a hover, but also when applying another div (Through JS).

To created the effect of the lines gradually shifting in color I used another element that slides on top of the original two lines. The new lines originally have 0 width, but on hover they gain 100% width. With a transition `transition: width 1000ms;` this happens gradually.

Try not to use my code as your final example, as it is somewhat ugly. But I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: Thanks Mitchel, The result seems to be what I want to achieve. I will dig into how this works after the weekend and come back on your answer.

Comment: Hi Mitchel, I read your code and fully understand how it's working, clever written if you ask me. May I know why you think it's not final-code-ready?

Comment: @BorisKamp It's mostly that it's a bit crude and unorganised. It's also not exactly responsive. Changing the size of each cube will result in having to change more values. All in all it's not too bad, but a bit of clean-up wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I'll do the cleaning and streamline the code once I implement it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small demonstration of css transition:

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover {
  border-color: blue;
  .box {
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

Or, check it on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ronency/75ozjq3s/

Answer (score 0):

```
.box {
    background: linear-gradient(80deg, #f3efef, #90009f, #01060d);
    background-size: 600% 600%;
    animation: AnimationName 29s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName { 
    0%{background-position:0% 51%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 51%}
}
```